# How to Send Image with Product order as custom option in SOAP API Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, soap, product-images, file-upload

While Ordering A Product [who have a custom option as file (image) required], through SOAP API , what will the value of KEY and VALUE pair, as per I know, key will the option id but what will be the value ??

For E.g.

```
           <options>
              <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
              <complexObjectArray>
                 <key>1</key>
                 <value>??????????????????</value>
              </complexObjectArray>
           </options>
```